# Parsing a JSON file with PHP

Tags: php, json, salesforce, apex, pmd

I'm trying to get data from the following JSON file using PHP. I specifically want the `@name` and additional parameters in the below hierarchy, parsed and put in a tabular format which can be easily read as html.

Considering we may be many types and sub-types wanted to understand the way it could be achieved in php, interactively.

It's probably really simple, but I have no idea how to do this. I'm stuck on what to do after 
`file_get_contents("output.json")`

```
{
  "{http://pmd.sourceforge.net/report/2.0.0}pmd": {
    "@{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}schemaLocation": "http://pmd.sourceforge.net/report/2.0.0 http://pmd.sourceforge.net/report_2_0_0.xsd",
    "@version": "6.4.0",
    "@timestamp": "2018-06-19T07:50:03.152",
    "{http://pmd.sourceforge.net/report/2.0.0}file": [{
        "@name": "/opt/folder/file.cls",
        "{http://pmd.sourceforge.net/report/2.0.0}violation": [{
            "@rule": "AvoidGlobalModifier",
            "@priority": "3",
            "@externalInfoUrl": "https://rule.html",
            "@endcolumn": "2",
            "@ruleset": "Best Practices",
            "@begincolumn": "30",
            "@beginline": "21",
            "@endline": "313",
            "#tail": "\n",
            "#text": "\nAvoid using global modifier\n"
        }, {
            "@rule": "StdCyclomaticComplexity",
            "@priority": "3",
            "@externalInfoUrl": "https://rule.html",
            "@endcolumn": "2",
            "@ruleset": "Design",
            "@begincolumn": "30",
            "@beginline": "21",
            "@endline": "313",
            "#tail": "\n",
            "#text": "\nThe class 'Class' has a Standard Cyclomatic Complexity of 5 (Highest = 18).\n"
        },  {
            "@rule": "ExcessiveParameterList",
            "@priority": "3",
            "@externalInfoUrl": "https://rule.html",
            "@endcolumn": "6",
            "@ruleset": "Design",
            "@begincolumn": "29",
            "@beginline": "219",
            "@endline": "242",
            "#tail": "\n",
            "#text": "\nAvoid long parameter lists\n"
        }, {
            "@rule": "Violation",
            "@priority": "3",
            "@externalInfoUrl": "https://rule.html",
            "@endcolumn": "14",
            "@ruleset": "Security",
            "@begincolumn": "16",
            "@beginline": "252",
            "@endline": "264",
            "#tail": "\n",
            "#text": "\nValidate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation\n"
        }],
        "#tail": "\n",
        "#text": "\n"
    }, {
        "@name": "/opt/folder/file2.cls",
        "{http://pmd.sourceforge.net/report/2.0.0}violation": {
            "@rule": "CRUDViolation",
            "@priority": "3",
            "@externalInfoUrl": "https://rule.html",
            "@endcolumn": "148",
            "@ruleset": "Security",
            "@begincolumn": "73",
            "@beginline": "15",
            "@endline": "15",
            "#tail": "\n",
            "#text": "\nValidate CRUD permission before SOQL/DML operation\n"
        },
        "#tail": "\n",
        "#text": "\n"
        }],
        "#text": "\n"
    }
}
```

Comment: search for and read about json_decode. Make certain your json is valid (hint : this one is not).

Comment: Thanks @YvesLeBorg . The Json is now validated with an extra '}' in the end. Somehow it was removed while pasting.

Answer (score -1):

To parse json I. PHP you be to use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

```
$content =file_get_contents("http://example.com/ex.json");
$jsonContent = json_decode($content,true)
```

**$jsonContent** contain your json data into an array thanks to second parameters.

This is a quick example you ve to check if content is not empty and if there is a json error.

Hope this helps

**EDIT** Sorry i was on my phone..